# How to 1. pass two datasets and 2.have permanent label on charts in Chartjs

Tags: jquery, chart.js

Anybody who has used [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) library before, could you please tell me:

1. if it's possible to pass two datasets to the pie/doughnut chart object (something like this:
    `var Piechart=new Chart(ctx).Pie(data1,data2,options);` 
   unlike the common call where we pass only one, as follows:
   `var Piechart=new Chart(ctx).Pie(data,options);`
   to achieve a pie chart like the one in the image shown.
2. Also, the figure value should be displayed permanently on the slice of the chart (instead of mouse hover and showing the tooltip icon )

[image]

Comment: @gibberish Could you please tell me how and where do I request the development team to consider my request for this new feature??

Comment: At the chartNew.js github repository, sign up for a github account (if you don't have one already) and post a new issue on the [chartNew.js issues page](https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js/issues). Don't specifically request a new feature, but rather ask the above question exactly as you did above (screenshot link and all). Good luck with it. I hope they treat you as well as they did me.

Answer (score 1):

You might also wish to consider the chart.js fork called [chartNew.js](https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js/).

chartNew.js is a fork of the 1.0 version of chart.js, but they retained the 1.0 format (keeping everything backwards compatible and, frankly, much simpler) but they added a number of new features (many of which are now included in chart.js version 2).

Additionally, the chartNew.js development team is very responsive and will often respond to [new posted issues](https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js/issues) (i.e. requests for help) very quickly.

There are some excellent sample solutions [here](https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js/tree/master/Samples)

Here is an example of the chartNew.js code:

```js
var mydata1 = {
 labels : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 datasets : [
  {
   fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0)",
   strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
   pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
   pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
   data : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  },
 ]
}
var mydata2 = {
 labels : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 datasets : [
  {
   fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0)",
   strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
   pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
   pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
   data : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  },
 ]
}

        
var setopts = {
    animation : false
}

var myLine1 = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas_1").getContext("2d")).Line(mydata1,setopts);

var myLine2 = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas_2").getContext("2d")).Line(mydata2,setopts);
```

```html
<SCRIPT src='https://rawgit.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js/master/ChartNew.js'></script>
<!-- <SCRIPT src='https://rawgit.com/nnnick/Chart.js/master/Chart.js'></script> -->

<canvas id="canvas_1" height="200" width="450"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas_2" height="200" width="450"></canvas>
```

And a couple of jsFiddle demos to play with:

[Above example](http://jsfiddle.net/9etwmL2a/10/)

[Example Two](https://jsfiddle.net/boxxevolution/wb64oL66/2/)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34056752/chartnew-js-update-corresponding-data-point-in-second-chart

Comment: @svik Moved from comment to answer in case it is worth upvoting